# Perl prepare DB2 statement not returning what I need

Tags: perl, db2, prepare

Since I am using DB2, in order to select a portion of a database in the middle (like a limit/offset pairing), I need to do a different kind of prepare statement.  The example I was given was this:

SELECT *
FROM (SELECT col1, col2, col3, ROW_NUMBER() OVER () AS RN FROM table) AS cols
WHERE RN BETWEEN 1 AND 10000;

Which I adapted to this:

SELECT * FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY 2,3,4,6,7 ASC) AS rownum FROM TRANSACTIONS) AS foo WHERE rownum >= 500 AND rownum <1000

And when I call the fetchall_arrayref(), I do come out with 500 results like I want to, but it is only returning an array with references to the row number, and not all of the data I want to pull.  I know for a fact that that is what the code is SUPPOSED to do as its written, and I have tried a bunch of permutations to get my desired result with no luck.

All I want is to grab all of the columns like my previous prepare statement into an array of arrays: 
SELECT * FROM TU_TRANSACTIONS ORDER BY 2, 3, 4, 6, 7

but just on a designated section.  There is just a fundamental thing I am missing, and I just cant see it.

Any help is appreciated, even if its paired with some constructive criticism.

Comment: have you tried RRN (relative Record number) instead of row_number?
SELECT T.*, RRN(T) FROM TU_TRANSACTIONS T WHERE RRN(T) BETWEEN 500 and 1000 ORDER BY 2,3,4,6,7

Answer (score 1):

Your table expression:

(SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY 2,3,4,6,7 ASC) AS rownum FROM TRANSACTIONS) as foo

Has only one column - rownum - so when you select "*" from "foo" you get only the one column.

Your table expression needs to include all of the columns you want, just like e example you posted.

Answer (score 0):

I don't use DB2 so I could be off-base but it seems that:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY 2,3,4,6,7 ASC) AS rownum FROM TRANSACTIONS) AS foo WHERE rownum >= 500 AND rownum <1000
```

Would only return the row numbers because while the sub-query references the table the main query does not. All it seems it would see is the set of numbers (which would return a single column with the number filled in)

Perhaps this would work:

```
SELECT * FROM TRANSACTIONS, (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY 2,3,4,6,7 ASC) AS rownum FROM TRANSACTIONS) AS foo WHERE rownum >= 500 AND rownum <1000
```

Comment: It was a good idea in theory, but I am getting an out of memory error, because I'm fairly certain that moving the transactions table is then pulling all of the information from transactions (which in itself, is a 1,000,000+ row database), ALONG with the extra column.  It honestly looked good to me and I tried it, but no luck :(